# Vmware Workstation 17 + Ubuntu20,04 + bridge network, Cannot ping VM after adding static arp entry

Tags: networking, arp

I am using Ubuntu20.04 VM in Vmware Workstation 17. I have setup a bridge network.

The VM eth0 has ip addr `192.168.1.5` and MAC addr `00-0c-29-ec-6a-bc`, the host has `192.168.1.4`

After disabling win10 firmware, I can ping VM from host, and ping host from VM.

However, after I add another entry `192.168.1.88` -> `00-0c-29-ec-6a-bc` and `192.168.1.88`. I get no response. The command to add the entry is `netsh interface ipv4 add neighbors Ethernet  192.168.1.88 00-0c-29-ec-6a-bc`

The arp table of host looks like this:

[image]

in which `192.168.1.5` is dynamic arp entry, `192.168.1.88` is static

My question is: why can't I ping `192.168.1.88`? what should I do to be able to ping it?